# Zend Db Field Comments

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

does anyone know if you can get individual field comments from mysql using Zend Db. What im working on is a registration form that gets all its fields from the db table.

At the moment im using the field names to generate the labels for the form elements however it would be much better to get this data from the information_schema.columns table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can. Here's the list of metadata returned from the Zend_Db_Table class - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.metadata.caching.hardcoding.

Comment: Im afraid I have to agree, I have done some more research and I think the only way of getting the info would be to manually query the information_schema.columns table.